# Prove $\{(x,y): x>0\}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, connectedness

As an introduction to multivariable calculus, I'm given a small introduction to some topological terminology and definitions. As the title says, I have to prove that $\{(x,y): x>0\}$ is connected. My tools for this are:

> **Definition 1**: Two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, neither empty, are said to be **mutually separated** if neither contains a boundary point of the other.
>
> **Definition 2**: A set is **disconnected** if it is the union of separated subsets.
>
> **Definition 3**: A set is **connected** if it is not disconnected.

Because **Definition 3** is a negation, I'm encouraged to do this by contradiction. Suppose $\{(x,y): x>0\}$ is disconnected. Then it is the union of mutually separated sets. I don't know where to go from here or if there is a way to show directly that the set can't be expressed as the union of mutually separated sets directly. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you happen to have a nice proof that $[0,1]$ is connected? The way I'd usually prove a set like this is connected is to show that it is *path-connected* (i.e. a continuous path may be drawn between any two points - here, a line segment suffices), which builds off of that fact.

Comment: @MiloBrandt in the current chapter of the book I'm using ("Advanced Calculus" by R. Creighton Buck) it is proven that a connected set is path connected and that the converse is also true but it will be proved until the next chapter. It seems the author expects one to prove this without the converse.

Comment: @Andrew: I think you mean the other way around. Path-connected set is always connected. And it is _not_ true that connected set is path-connected. However, connected _open_ subset of euclidean space is indeed path-connected.

Comment: @Prism sorry, what is proven is that any open connected set is path connected. Then mentions that later it will be proven that any path connected is also connected

Comment: @AndrewGSM: Oh I see. Thanks for clarification. Ironically, proving that "path-connected set is connected" is much easier to prove than showing that "open connected set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is path-connected".

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but here's one way:

The function $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x, y)=(e^x, y)$ is continuous. The continuous image of a connected set is connected. The image of $f$ is precisely $\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x>0\}$.

Comment: In other words, the open half-plane is topologically the same as the entire plane.

Comment: It might be useful for someone else and certainly for me later in the course, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The weird thing about connectedness is that proof by contradiction is sort of the direct way to prove it. The definition of connected is *negative*. A set is connected if it is *not* satisfying a certain condition. So to contradict that would be to assume a set *is* satisfying a certain condition, and therein is why it gets a pseudo-direct feel to it. I recommend doing the proof by contradiction as you were already encouraged.

The first thing I'd do is draw in the $x$-$y$ plane (or have a clear mental picture of) your set. You need to prove that no matter how you split that set into two pieces that those two pieces cannot both be mutually separated. So proceed as you say by assuming the existence of two mutually separated sets $A,B$ whose union is your set. You didn't provide your definition of boundary point, but use the fact that $A$ and $B$ cannot contain a boundary point of the other. Then choose a boundary point and see what else you can say about it. Keep trying to find things you can say until you find you have reached a contradiction. The contradiction may not be immediately clear, but if you play around with these definitions for a while something should pop out for you.